# Do humans use the doppler effect to localize sources of sound?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acoustics, frequency, doppler-effect, ultrasound

Consider a source of sound such as a person speaking or a party of people which makes a continual drone sound of the the same frequency. If a human shakes their head side-to-side with sufficient angular speed, they are in effect obtaining different frequencies of the same sound source and should be able to apply [the Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) to approximately localize (from prior experience) the sound source.

> Do humans use the Doppler effect to localize sources of sound and have there been any studies proving this?

*Edit:* A [link to the Weber-Fechner law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber%E2%80%93Fechner_law) and a [link to the wiki article discussing the just-noticable-difference (JND) for music applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-noticeable_difference#Music_production_applications) were added to the OP for reference, based on the accepted answer.

Comment: Note: we will localize it quite effectively based on frequency responses of the ear, which differ from direction to direction.

Comment: Expounding on @CortAmmon 's comment, the unique shape and ridges in our ears help to shape how our ears receive different frequencies. If you were to use clay to mold a smooth shape to your outer ears, you would lose the ability to localise sound. As demonstrated in a youtube video experiment performed on his own son by SmarterEveryDay.

Comment: @GlenYates More precise to say that the ability to [localize sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization) is *compromised* by such a modification - but it is not fully **lost**.  Modifying the shape of the ear only attacks one of our many mechanisms used to localize sound.  It's an important one, but it is certainly not the *only* one.

Comment: @J... True, I forgot about localising left vs right by the time delta that sound is received among other things. We apparently use frequency analysis that is helped shaped by the shape of our ears to localise sounds that would otherwise be identical in time between left and right ears - such as whether a sound came from in front of you or behind you. It was this ability that was lost with somewhat comical effect in the mentioned video.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A person would not be able to localize a sound using the Doppler effect created by shaking their head.

Say a person shakes their head at 20 cm/s.  The speed of sound is about 330 m/s.  This gives a frequency change of 0.06%.

The "just noticeable difference" to discern two frequencies played in succession is about 0.6% ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-noticeable_difference#Music_production_applications)), so about an order of magnitude too coarse.

Comment: @NiharKarve: Thanks. I've added a link, where 0.6% is the first sentence of the second paragraph under Music Production Applications.

Comment: ...but coherent doppler sensors usually measure a phase shift, not a frequency shift. (So it's the change in position, not the speed, that creates the signal).

Comment: Running the numbers in my head, that suggests the just-noticeable difference is achieved by someone walking past (3.6km/h walking pace = 1 m/s = 0.3% of 330m/s, double it for approaching/receding).  That feels right to me: I used to work with a part-time firefighter.  When his emergency phone went off he sprinted out of work with it still sounding, and the shift was very clear (the ringtone was a two-tone siren - people got out of his way)

Comment: Sounds are affected by head angle anyway, so an erroneous signal could be perceived with shaking, but fast vs. slow shaking or indeed holding the extreme positions of the shake doesn't affect the pitch. As the ears are so near the axis of rotation, the linear motion is rather small.  To get 20cm/s would seem to need very fast shaking indeed

Comment: We don't use the doppler effect, but the brain **does** cue off of the time delay between a sound reaching either ear.  A sound coming from your left will hit the left eardrum almost a millisecond before the right.  The brain can sense this difference and "moves" the sound to the left of your virtual soundstage in response.  This can even be simulated with time delays in headphones where both sounds are otherwise identical (ie: no filtering, same volume, etc) - to distinguish from other cues like your head blocking high frequencies, etc.

Comment: @ChrisH one guess is that because the brain (software) is adept at recognizing tonal variation of sounds we need very little frequency change between two waves to apply (implicitly) Doppler. Head shaking or moving (twitching) the ear drums in a small time interval but fast enough speed could therefore be a feasible way we can do this.

Comment: @J... thanks for the great comment. If you think that is the primary method we use to localize sounds, please do add any relevant references.

Comment: @kb314 It's not cutting edge research - this is just general knowledge.  The phenomena are quite well understod. Wikipedia [documents it adequately](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization).  Time delays are not the only cue the brain uses, but it is one of them.

Comment: @J... thanks for the link.

Comment: @kb314 No trouble.  Worth noting, also, that the doppler effect is never really used for sound localization because it can't really give you that information.  The doppler effect more specifically gives you information about the *velocity* of an object, not its position.  Straight echolocation gives you the position of an object, but adding the frequency processing to extract the doppler shift adds the velocity component as well.

Comment: @J... I understand that Doppler effect would directly lead us to speed measurement, but we could use the signal to integrate it for time.

Comment: @kb314 Yes, measuring the time delay between a trigger and echo pulse is called *echolocation* (in animals, or Sonar in technology) and this is different from a doppler measurement.  A doppler measurement is echolocation **plus** an additional measurement of the frequency shift of the time-delayed return pulse.

Answer (score 1):

Humans DO use dopler effect to estimate a sound source position, they just dont use it exactly the way you imagine.

The simplest example is the distance to a passing by object (a car, an airplane, a mosqito or even a talking human). A near flyby makes a rapidly lowering tone. An object passing away from you will change its tone slower.

Moving your head left and right gets you a direction by the phase difference between ears. Well, you can get the direction withour moving your head, but it will be exact up to the symmetry of your head.